# __doPostBack does not work

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dopostback

I have a master page and in this page `__doPostBack`doesn't fire a post back. But I have another master page that __doPostBack works and it seems everything is the same with this other master page but __doPostBack does not work after all...

What could possibly be the reason for this?

```
<%@ Master Language="VB"  AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="xx.master.vb" Inherits="MyProject.xx" %>

<asp:Button type="button" ID="btnSwitchLanguage" Style="display: none" runat="server" />

__doPostBack("<%= btnSwitchLanguage.UniqueID %>", lang_id);


Private Sub btnSwitchLanguage_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSwitchLanguage.Click
    'Do Something
End Sub
```

Comment: have you tried `Page.GetPostBackEventReference(btnSwitchLanguage)` instead?

Comment: actually in this page not a single postback works.. it doesn't even refresh the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too weird but I solved the problem.

Here was the reason:

In project we override __doPostBack function, I didn't notice it. But in the other master page it was overriden just fine, in the one I'm talking about isn't.

In the other master page the __doPostBack func will become like this:

```
__doPostBack(Param1, Param2)
{
    var theform;
    if (window.navigator.appName.toLowerCase().indexOf('netscape') > -1)
    {
        theform = document.forms['aspnet…
```

But in the master I'm dealing with:

```
__doPostBack()
{
   return;
}
```

It's weird because the order of javascript is the same too!

Anyway, I prevent __doPostBack from be overriden and the problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to put the code in function like this :

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="postBack();return false;"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            function postBack(){
                var btnName = $get("<%=Btn2.ClientID%>").name;
                __doPostBack(btnName,"");
            }
        </script>
```

Hopes this help you.